# a faster way of decompressing a large zip file

Tags: c#, .net, zip

I am writing a program that extracts images from zip file and catalogues them.

`System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory` seems to work fine for smaller files but it is really really slow for *big files* (>4GB), is there a faster library out there? I don't need anything special just to extract the zip file into a directory.

Comment: Have you checked it isn't just the amount of data to move: is the current implementation IO bound? If your IO speed is the limiting factor no code changes will make significant difference.

Comment: How slow is *really slow*? How long will the code which simply write to new file will take for same amount of bytes?

Comment: I'm testing with a 8.9GB file which basically contains a reference file (csv) and thousands of images, I started the program test at 10am this morning and it is still going... 5+ hours, it has extracted 85000+ up to now

Comment: Maybe the bottleneck is the hardware (tried it on a SSD or RAM drive)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 7-zip 
http://www.7-zip.org/download.html

```
    public static string[] UnpackZip(string file, string targetDirectory)
    {
        Process p = new Process();
        string unzip = "x -y \"-o" + targetDirectory + "\" \"" + file + "\" ";
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "7z.exe";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = unzip;
        p.Start();
        p.WaitForExit();
        if (p.ExitCode != 0)
            throw new Exception("Errore durante l'unzip " + p.ExitCode + " - " + unzip);
        return Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory);
    }
```

Comment: Does this requires 7-zip installed on the machine? I am extracting in a remote server, not sure I'll have access to 7-zip

Comment: no need to install, just put exe and dll into your exe dir